# Can I connect the negative terminals together on two LED drivers?

Tags: led, led-strip

I have a white, adjustable-color-temperature LED strip that I'm trying to power. The LED is basically composed of two separate LED circuits -- one at 6500K and another at 2700K. The strip has one positive lead for each circuit and a shared negative lead.

Can I connect matched, constant voltage, dimmable LED drivers like this? Is that crazy?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSZgPc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Transformers don't have positive/negative terminals. Do you actually have a pair of dimmable LED power-supplies/drivers?

Comment: Since his "transformer" is AC-in DC-out my guess is that those are actually DC Power supplies. Is this crazy ? **No** this should work fine ! So go ahead and connect like you suggested.

Comment: I agree, common ground is usually ok, although some IC current drivers for LEDs taking power from the mains ride on the high side, creating virtual grounds...

Comment: @FakeMoustache : unless they are too cheap to provide isolation. Which might be the case for LED power supplies intended for permanently wired installations. So while I agree you're probably right, I'm a little cautious about it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I agree, some IC drivers i have seen use buck converters floating on the high side... Since you have seen it also, it must be prevalent. So on second thought, OP proceed with caution. Maybe first measure the -DC rails with a multimeter to see if there is a potential difference. If there is, try it again with them connected via a 10k resistor.

Comment: Most led strip controllers I've seen use a common Anode setup, with a low side/n-channel Fet for control. Common Cathode is rare.

Comment: @FakeMoustache You're totally right. It's a dimmable LED driver, not a transformer -- either Lutron's Hi-Lume A-Series (http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/LEDDrivers/Hi-LumeLED/Overview.aspx) or a Zurik magnetic power supply (http://www.flexfireleds.com/zurik-magnetic-dimmable-led-drivers/60w-12v-zurik-led-dimmable-driver/)

Comment: lutron says "Class 2 rated output available" so @OlinLathrop is correct, the output is isolated. there;s no guarantee that this won't mess up your 0-10V control though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Dimmable transformer" makes no sense, so I don't know what those blocks on the left are.  Transformers put out AC, which your LEDs aren't going to like much.

I'll assume these things are some kind of power supply.  Since line AC is coming in and these are intended for consumers, I'll also assume they are isolated.  In that case, you can hook them up as you propose.  Each will drive one LED string without getting in the way of the other.

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken. I edited the question and replaced transformer with LED driver.